# How do I filter a custom posts by a field in wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress, filter, field, custom-post-type

OK, very simple task, I'm just not good at PHP.

I have a page where I want to list some staff using a styled list. Here is the page - http://www.themontessoripeople.co.uk/montesori/?post_type=people

I downloaded a "custom content type" plugin and added the content type of "people" and added the appropriate fields. Now I want to filter the posts I have added by the custom field called "hierarchy".

Here is how I want the page to display - http://i47.tinypic.com/oqymwh.jpg

The custom field "hierarchy" contains the room variables of either "management", "babies_room" and "toddlers_room".

How do I amend the code below to filter the posts by the value held within `<?php print_custom_field('hierarchy'); ?>` ?

```
<?php $col = 1; ?>      
    <?php if (have_posts()) : ?>        
        <?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>         
            <?php if ($col == 1) echo "<div class=\"row\">"; ?>

                <div class="post col<?php echo $col;?>" id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>">

                            <div class="people-spacer">

                                <div class="people"><a class="animate" >
                                <div class="bio">
                                <p class="titles"><?php the_title(); ?><br/>
                                <span class="job"> <?php print_custom_field('job'); ?></span> </p><br />
                                </div>
                                <img src="<?php print_custom_field('staff_image:to_image_src'); ?>" width="160" height="160" alt="<?php the_title(); ?>-image" />
                                </div>
                                <div class="people-link-edit"><?php edit_post_link('Edit Post', ''); ?></div>
                            </div>
                </div>

            <?php if ($col == 1) echo "</div>"; (($col==1) ? $col=2 : $col=2); ?>   
        <?php endwhile; ?>
```

Thanks, Ben.

Here is the working code showing two sets of filtered results for reference -

```
<?php $col = 1; ?>
<?php if (have_posts()) : ?>


<div class="text-box">

<h2>Management</h2>
<?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
<?php if (get_custom_field('hierarchy') != "management") continue; ?>

<?php if ($col == 1) echo "<div class=\"row\">"; ?>
<div class="post col<?php echo $col;?>" id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>">
 <div class="people-spacer">
  <div class="people"><a class="animate" >
   <div class="bio">
    <p class="titles">
     <?php the_title(); ?>
     <br/>
     <span class="job"> <?php print_custom_field('job'); ?></span> </p>
    <br />
   </div>
   <img src="<?php print_custom_field('staff_image:to_image_src'); ?>" width="160" height="160" alt="<?php the_title(); ?>-image" /> </div>
  <div class="people-link-edit">
   <?php edit_post_link('Edit Post', ''); ?>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
<?php if ($col == 1) echo "</div>"; (($col==1) ? $col=2 : $col=2); ?>
<?php endwhile; ?>

</div><!-- close text box -->


<div class="text-box">

<h2>Babies Room</h2>

<?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
<?php if (get_custom_field('hierarchy') != "babies_room") continue; ?>

<?php if ($col == 1) echo "<div class=\"row\">"; ?>
<div class="post col<?php echo $col;?>" id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>">
 <div class="people-spacer">
  <div class="people"><a class="animate" >
   <div class="bio">
    <p class="titles">
     <?php the_title(); ?>
     <br/>
     <span class="job"> <?php print_custom_field('job'); ?></span> </p>
    <br />
   </div>
   <img src="<?php print_custom_field('staff_image:to_image_src'); ?>" width="160" height="160" alt="<?php the_title(); ?>-image" /> </div>
  <div class="people-link-edit">
   <?php edit_post_link('Edit Post', ''); ?>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
<?php if ($col == 1) echo "</div>"; (($col==1) ? $col=2 : $col=2); ?>
<?php endwhile; ?>

</div><!-- close text box -->
```

Comment: I think this would get answered faster if it were asked on the wordpress stack exchange site

Comment: Trust me, it doesn't. I've asked twice already - http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/66216/how-do-i-filter-a-custom-post-type-loop-by-a-field :s

Comment: wordpress stack exchange is not even close to as useful as stack overflow. Most WP questions can be posed and "genericised" to be just a programming question (and many programmers know the basics of how the PHP platform of WordPress works)

Answer (score 1):

I've simplified your code. The filter is added too:

```
<?php
    $col = 1;
    while (have_posts())
    {
        the_post();
        if ($col == 1) echo "<div class=\"row\">";

        // filter
        $hierarchy = get_custom_field('hierarchy');
        // if it does not match continue (skip)
        if ($hierarchy != "boss") continue;
        // if it matches continue (skip)
        //if ($hierarchy == "notboss") continue;

        // needed fields
        $id = the_ID();
        $job = get_custom_field('job');
        $title = the_title();
        $img = get_custom_field('staff_image:to_image_src');
        $edit = edit_post_link('Edit Post', '');

        echo <<< END
                <div class="post col$col" id="post-$id">
                    <div class="people-spacer">
                        <div class="people"><a class="animate" >
                        <div class="bio">
                        <p class="titles">$title<br/>
                        <span class="job">$job</span> </p><br />
                        </div>
                        <img src="$img" width="160" height="160" alt="$title-image" />
                        </div>
                        <div class="people-link-edit">$edit</div>
                    </div>
                </div>
END;

        if ($col == 1) echo "</div>";
        (($col==1) ? $col=2 : $col=2);
    }
?>
```

Edit: get_custom_field instead of print_custom_field.

Comment: Hey Andreas, thanks for your time. I added the code to the template file and when browsed to the page did not show. I've tried adding the filters to the original code and it just prints the value next to each post. I thought maybe it could be a simple syntax mistake breaking it but DW returned none. If you would like to give it another go I can give you the login of the test site and you can eliminate the chance of me messing it up. The test has everything in place for testing. Thanks again, Ben.

Comment: please try to comment // the if ($hierarchy) part

Comment: I've tried the amended code but the page still won't load :( I just get a white page. I'm worried I'm putting it in the wrong place or that something I have on the page already is conflicting.

If you would be so kind here is the test site - [link]http://www.irishofcourse.co.cc/montesori/wp-admin/profile.php?updated=true

login:s14 pass:rehm

The template I'm testing on is - 
Main Index Template
(index.php)

here is the page the function effects http://www.irishofcourse.co.cc/montesori/?post_type=people

You can mess it up, I'm not using it for testing anymore.
Thanks again Ben.

Comment: Andreas, I somehow managed to get it to work! Unbelievably. Thank you so much for your help, it was your code that I cut up and used to get it working. I'll append the working code to the question for everyone to see the outcome. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

You can define query args in `query_posts($args)` - have a look at [query_posts](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/query_posts). Maybe you can try `get_posts`

Comment: Don't use query_posts, blech. Use the WP_Query class instead. - http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query